# SwiftUI3 navigation link doesn't work after pop if stack size > 1

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

`SwiftUI 3` navigation link doesn't work after pop if stack size > 1

Steps to reproduce:

1. Launch the app
2. Tap any row in list #1
3. Tap any row in list #2
4. Tap `Back`
5. Tap any row in list #2

Result: nothing happens, navigation link doesn't work
Expected result: I should see view controller #3 again.

[image: navigation-issue-demo-gif]

Works fine in `SwiftUI 2` though.

Was anyone able to make nested `NavigationLinks` work in Swift UI 3? I have filed an error report to Apple.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct NavigationTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            FirstView()
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                    NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                        Text("Row \(i)")
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("1"))
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                NavigationLink(destination: ThirdView()) {
                    Text("Child \(i)")
                        .padding()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(Text("2"))
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("")
        }
        .navigationTitle(Text("3"))
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a known issue per release notes look under SwiftUI https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-15-beta-release-notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @loremipsum said, it's a known issue

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-15-beta-release-notes

SwiftUI Known Issues
You can’t push to a third screen after popping from a third screen in the navigation stack. (79076444)